# Importing multiple py files in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdfs

I have the below folder structure in hdfs.

/home/myid
-main.py
-test1.py
-test2.py

In main.py I am trying to import both test1 and test2.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc=SparkContext('local')
spark= SparkSession(sc)
from test1 import test_function
from test2 import new_function

test_function()
new_function()
```

All 3 files are in same folder.

Test1.py

```
def test_function():
    print("test1")
```

Test2.py

```
def new_function():
    print("test2")
```

When I try to execute main.py using
spark-submit main.py, it says cannot import new_function.

It is able to import test1.py but not test2.py

I also tried with sc.addPyFile before import. Didn't work.

Tried by giving --py-files along with spark submit and it didn't  work either.

Tried zipping both the test1 and test2 and added it along with spark context. It didn't work either.

Trying to understand why it's not working and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Try giving with these syntax using `spark-submit`, make sure you are using comma

```
--py-files test1.py,test2.py
```

**Option 2:**

moreover you can `zip` them and include like this

First put them in a directory for instance `myfiles/` ( In addition make empty `__init__.py` file at root level in this directory like myfiles/__init__.py )

From outside this directory,make a zip of it (for example `myfiles.zip`)

Now include this zip with `sc.addPyFile`function

```
sc.addPyFile("myfiles.zip")
```

Considering your have `__init__.py` , `test1.py` and `test2.py` in `myfiles.zip`

You can now use them as

```
from myfiles.Test1 import test_function
from myfiles.Test2 import new_function
```

Comment: Tried already and yes with a comma between files. Spark-submit /home/myid/test1.py, /home/myid/test2.py main.py

Comment: And what about zip option?

Comment: I have updated the zip steps to include some common pitfalls, let me know if it helps

Comment: Sure.. will try it out now

Comment: Also, for spark submit, Have you tried with `--py-files`, I dont see this in your comment

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response... this doesn't work too.. :(

Comment: Followed the zip process as per above. Still unable to import function in second file. Cannot import name new_function is the error

Comment: It worked now.. I did a small mistake.. corrected now. Thanks

Comment: With multiple files separated by a comma instead of a space in`--py-files`, you can then also add other arguments to your actual python program. Both space and comma work for `--py-files`. But if you use a space, it seems you cannot add arguments to your program, because of how arguments are treated (are they arguments for spark-submit, or for your program?)